# in windows package resource of cookbook -installer_type showing error

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

While am executing this package resource in a cookbook, it shows the following error:

```
windows_package 'PuTTY version 0.60' do
  source 'http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty-0.60-installer.exe'  
  installer_type :inno
  action :install
end
```

I get this error:

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option installer_type must be a kind of [String]!  You passed :inno.
```

I also tried `:msi,:custom`, same error only. Also for exe files we need `:inno` type only.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're using a recent version of Chef that has `windows_package` built into it.

Unfortunately, it doesn't support types other than "msi" (and yes, it's a string now)

If you want to install Inno packages, depend on the 'windows' cookbook in your cookbook metadata, and that cookbook's `windows_package` provider will override the one out-of-the-box, thereby allowing you to install other packages.